# How to convert a html page into a native iPhone view?

Tags: iphone, html, ios

I would like to replicate the Stackoverflow "[Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" page, to be run natively on the iPhone. The view contains two text boxes (a title and a text section) and a submit button.

When I press the submit button, how do I send the contents of the view to Stackoverflow?

What relevant iOS classes do I need to use?

Is it possible to do this without any APIs? I want a generic solution for any website.

Comment: You could reskin it for example and add in the following line of code to fit the iPhone's screen width, assuming portrait orientation: <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=false" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *body = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"title=%@&post-text=%@", title, question]; 
NSData *requestBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];

NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

White woking with StackOverflow in particular in a native iPhone app you'll have to use API:

https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the StackOverflow's API?

Comment: You don't need the SO API to build the view but you need to use it to interact with SO. It is very simple to use, just a simple HTTP call, nothing extraordinary. I think for low load apps you don't even need a key.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested in a generic solution rather than one for SO.